# On server side rendering of react using node , chrome converts http to https and throws an error while using aws ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-ec2

I am new to programming using react and nodejs. So I made a to-do list which was working fine on my local system but when I deploy it on aws ec2 instance, the script present in my build folder (formed after npm run build) is getting converted from HTTP to HTTPS on chrome and throws an error. 
When I copy the link and replace HTTPS with HTTP and use postman, the URL is executing correctly and giving the desired result.

On my local system, this script runs as

http://localhost:3002/static/js/1.2c1180f3.chunk.js,
http://localhost:3002/static/js/main.afeba04b.chunk.js

whereas on the ec2 instance it runs as

https://ec2-18-188-23-132.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3002/static/css/main.3f1cc57d.chunk.css,

https://ec2-18-188-23-132.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3002/static/js/1.2c1180f3.chunk.js